# HOW TO CHANGE THE MESSAGE: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Tags: php, file, size

Hello this generic message appears whenever you lower the upload file size and then try to upload file with bigger than the specified size in php.ini
I don't seek how to fix it,
I want to change what the message says, but I just can't find where.
The web is full with how to fix it answers :)
Thank you!

Comment: That's not a PHP warning. So it's being printed out specifically by whatever software or code you are keeping a secret. Use a file search tool of your choosing, and find the echo/print associated with that string.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is catch the exception and change to a "nice" message, you'll need to wrap the upload in a try catch and test for the following exception type `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`.

From there you can simply edit/change/replace the message with one that you like.

It's worth noting that there is more error messages you may wish to handle, and they are listed in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

This is "straight" PHP, so there may be a small amount needed for WordPress, I don't have a WP install handy at this moment.

```
try {
    //upload stuff
} catch (Exception $e) {
    switch($_FILES['file']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            //for completeness sake
            $message = "File Uploaded Successfully";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            $message = "No file was uploaded";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            $message = "Missing a temporary folder";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            $message = "Failed to write file to disk";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            $message = "File upload stopped by extension";
            break;
        default:
            $message = "Unknown upload error";
            break;
    }
    //deal with returning the message here
}
```

Simply edit the `$message` to be what you wish with whatever custom message you please.

Comment: I'm very sorry, could you give directions to my poor soul to some kind of a wordpress filter which will do the stuff.
I'm a complete noob.
If you don't want to bother I will understand.

Comment: maybe this :
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload_error' ) ) {
    function wp_handle_upload_error( &$file, $message ) {
        return array( 'error'=>$message );
    }
}
But no idea how to make it work as a filter

Comment: you didn't state you were using wordpress, maybe add that to your post and the tag so it's clearer. i'll see if i can update my message to be a bit clearer

Comment: Yes, been 34h+ with no sleep, sorry. Thank you!